# Showing RTL languages in cmd & vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, visual-studio-code

I'm using python for web scraping but when I want to extract contents from a page, the Persian contents don't show correctly. CMD shows squares instead of letters and VSCode shows letters separated and disorderly.
Even when I print a simple Persian word, the problem doesn't solve.

I change the font and I change the encoding (default encoding is UTF-8) and none of them helps.

The "سلام" word showed "م‌ا‌ل‌س" in VSCode.

Comment: try to write those words in a txt file and see if they behave same.

Comment: I tried this way too and nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: What version are you using? I don't face this on v1.36.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: 1.38.0 on windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Persian word in vscode terminal Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516516/how-to-print-persian-word-in-vscode-terminal-python)