# How to print Persian word in vscode terminal Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and when I try to print this

```
print('شیرینی پزی')
```

the output of terminal is

```
ی‌ز‌پ ی‌ن‌ی‌ر‌ی‌ش
```

what should I do

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: The following solution is for displaying the RTL texts. Don't use the output in your code. It's just for printing in wherever RTL texts are messed up.

First install `arabic_reshaper` and `bidi`

```sh
pip install arabic-reshaper
pip install python-bidi
```

Then, use the following function:

```py
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

def convert(text):
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
    converted = get_display(reshaped_text)
    return converted
print(convert('شیرینی پزی'))
```

The output:

```py
>>> شیرینی پزی
```